# Rounds of Games

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

Each of two teams has seven players numbered 1 to 7. In the first game, the two players numbered 1 play each other. The loser of each game is eliminated and replaced by the next player of the same team, until all players from one team have been eliminated. Let $N$ be the number of possible sequences of games. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by 1000.

I listed out possible outcomes when there was 1 player, 2 player, ... and the number was 2^something but I got 2097152 and I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Retry counting - I get 6 when $n$ is 2

Comment: round 1: A1B1
r2: A2B1 or A1B2
r3: A2B2, A3B1, A2B2, A1B3
r4:A3B2, A2B3, A4B1, A3B2, A3B2, A2B3...

Comment: 2^k is right track but you went too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as the number of combinations leading to victory in a best-of-$13$ series that ends when one team has clinched the series.  Let's assume team $A$ is the winner (and we must remember to multiply our final result by $2$ to account for the possibility that $B$ is the winner).

$A$ can win exactly $6$ of the first $k+6$ games, and then Game $k+7$ (ending the series in exactly $k+7$ games), in $\binom {k+6}{6}=\binom{k+6}{k}$ ways, so we want

$$2\sum_{k=0}^6 \binom {k+6}{k}.$$

This is $2 \cdot (1+7+28+84+210+462+924)= 3432$.

There's another way to get this answer.  Each combination of $14$ (not $13$) games resulting in exactly $7$ wins for each team yields a unique combination fitting the conditions, so there are $\binom  {14}{7}$ possible combinations.  To see that this is a bijection, given such a combination, cut it off when the first team reaches $7$ wins and you get a permissible series.  Conversely, given a permissible series, allow the losing team to win all of the remaining (unplayed because superfluous) games, and you end up with a $7$-$7$ tie.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: If we write each possible match as $(a, b)$ when the $a$th player from team A goes against the $b$th player from team B, then each match has 2 outcomes - if the team A player wins then the next match is $(a, b+1)$, and if the team B player wins the next match is $(a+1, b)$ - noting that if $a+1$ or $b+1$ is bigger than the number of players on that team, then that marks the end of the tournament. You could draw it as a grid where you move right when team A wins and down when team B wins, noting that you never go left or up.

Then you need to consider:

1. Is every path through the grid a valid sequence of matches?
2. Is every path through the grid a unique sequence of matches?
3. How can you most efficiently count all of those paths, noting that each time you progress through the grid there are either 2 or 0 possible choices at the next step?

You've definitely made some progress noting that powers of 2 are relevant.

Comment: I prefer to define $(a,b)$ as the number of players eliminated from team A and B respectively. Then all we need to do is calculate the North - East lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(7,7)$

Answer (score 1):

The lattice diagram of all states can be shown like this.

```
                  11
                12  21
              13  22  31
            14  23  32  41  
          15  24  33  42  51 
        16  25  34  43  52  61
      17  26  35  44  53  62  71
        27  36  45  54  63  72
          37  46  55  64  73
            47  56  65  74
              57  66  75
                67  76
                  77
```

counting all paths are easy (2 outcomes for each game). Due to various symmetries you actually need to construct only the quarter of this but visualization helps to build intuition.